# How do I get to a JSON Object that changes its name all the time

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio, wikipedia

I want to get the main Image URL from Wikipedia, but the problem is that the pageID always changes and now i dont know how i get to the URL.
This is the api request

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php? 
action=query&titles=Max_Verstappen&prop=pageimages&pithumbsize=300&format=json
```

This is the response

```
    {
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "normalized": [
            {
                "from": "Max_Verstappen",
                "to": "Max Verstappen"
            }
        ],
        "pages": {
            "41758713": {
                "pageid": 41758713,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Max Verstappen",
                "thumbnail": {
                    "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/75/Max_Verstappen_2017_Malaysia_3.jpg/200px-Max_Verstappen_2017_Malaysia_3.jpg",
                    "width": 200,
                    "height": 300
                },
                "pageimage": "Max_Verstappen_2017_Malaysia_3.jpg"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code now I thought I will work my way through to the URL with this code

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
JSONObject query = jsonObject.getJSONObject("query");
JSONObject pages = jsonObject.getJSONObject("pages");
```

But now i get to the point where I have to know the pageID, but I cant because I want to get many urls from many Wikipedia articles.
So is there an easier way to get to the url?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply get the key value of the object :

```
JSONObject pages = jsonObject.getJSONObject("pages");
for (String key : pages.keys()) {
    System.out.println(key); // will print '41758713' from your example
}
```

[JSONObject.keys()](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys--)